# COM3 reg key deleted, COM+ component services not working - how do i restore?

Tags: windows-7, registry, components, com+, component-services

I was looking in to migration of one of our in house applications from XP to Win7. While doing this, I removed the COM3 registry key from: HKEY_LOACL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/MICROSOFT/COM3. (I did not back it up. lesson learned)

Since doing this I now get the following error:

[image]

Is there a way to re-install COM+ component services? And will that fix the reg key that I removed? What other actions could I take if that doesn't work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no way to restore the com+ service. I had to re-image the machine.
Sources: MS tele support, Local IT support, web.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regsvr32` with the DLL to re-register the components within the DLL. Don't know what the right arguments are in your situation, and there are some mild drawbacks to doing it this way, but it seems like what you need to recover from a disaster.

Comment: This method may lead to something. If anyone else has any knowledge on it please share.

Comment: Your solution will fix installed components, but my problem is the component service its self, not the DLLs within it. I think I may need to re-install windows based on what I'm reading, and hearing from co-workers.

Comment: Oh, that is more serious. I don't recall if that service arises from registering a DLL. I half-recall that it is, but I'm not sure.